# Set IAM role to run AWS CLI Python subprocess in AWS Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-cli, aws-lambda-layers

I created a Lambda layer that contains the AWS CLI because the `aws sync` command is not available in boto3 and the copy function was too slow to complete the s3 to s3 transfer prior to hitting the maximum Lambda time out.

I can run AWS CLI commands (ls, sync, etc) as the execution role for the Lambda. I need to run `aws sync` from Lambda to sync two s3 buckets **as a different IAM user** that has access to the source and destination buckets.

*How do I configure the CLI to run as a particular user?*

The commands below configure the user successfully locally but when run using the subprocess function in Lambda, the output of get-caller-identity is still the ARN of the Lambda role.

```
/opt/aws configure set aws_access_key_id <id>
/opt/aws configure set aws_secret_access_key <key>
/opt/aws sts get-caller-identity
```

In order to run the configure set id and key commands, I had to set an environmental variable to bypass the read only Lambda file system to write the credentials to the /temp directory.

**Environmental Variable:**

```
key: HOME
value: /tmp
```

Note: There is a populated credentials file written to: /temp/.aws/credentials

**Lambda:**

```
import logging
import subprocess

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def run_command(command):
    command_list = command.split(' ')
    try:
        logger.info("Running shell command: \"{}\"".format(command))
        result = subprocess.run(command_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE);
        logger.info("Command output:\n---\n{}\n---".format(result.stdout.decode('UTF-8')))
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Exception: {}".format(e))
        return False

    return True

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    run_command('/opt/aws configure set aws_access_key_id <id>')
    run_command('/opt/aws configure set aws_secret_access_key <key>')
    # not set to new IAM user
    run_command('/opt/aws sts get-caller-identity')
```

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the IAM access credentials as [environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html) to the subprocess, instead of trying to run `aws configure`:

```
result = subprocess.run(command_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, env={
  'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID': <id>,
  'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY': <id>,
});
```

---

**Explanation:**

The Lambda runtime environment has the environment variables set for the role it is using, [documented here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html), and those environment variables are [taking precedence](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html) over anything you are trying to do via the `aws configure` command. So the easiest way to fix that is to just override the environment variables that are passed to the subprocess via the `env` argument.

I don't think your calls to `aws configure` are working anyway, since all that does is write to a `~/.aws/credentials` file, and that file isn't writeable inside the AWS Lambda environment, only `/tmp` is writeable.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for the solution and specific documentation links. I was able to get it working with one minor change. I replaced the '=' to ':' in the env={} key/value assignments. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Glad I could help. I fixed the syntax in the answer for anyone else that finds this.